# Why am I getting an error message "no module named nameparser.parser"?

Tags: python, nltk

When I am compiling my code, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
   from nameparser.parser import HumanName
ImportError: No module named nameparser.parser
```

How do I rectify it?

Comment: Do you have the library installed?

Comment: So....if the answer helped, you should mark your question solved. If it didn't - provide additional details.

Answer (score 5):

Works fine for me. Maybe, you haven't installed the module? Try something like

```
pip install nameparser
```

in your command line. Or `sudo pip install nameparser`, if this doesn't work.

P.S. Btw, you are most probably not 'compiling' your code ;)

Comment: error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nameparser': Permission denied

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_vandana/nameparser/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-4Rd7GE-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_vandana/nameparser Storing debug log for failure in /home/vandana/.pip/pip.log

Comment: `sudo pip install nameparser`? Edited the post.

Comment: @user3787793 Forgo to add your nickname to the comment. See the edited post.

Comment: Finally got it installed.